# Multiple optimistic updates in RTK Query mutation

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

What's the recommended way to optimistically update the singular (getDocument) and plural (getDocuments) after a createDocument mutation?

Here's my simplified attempt:

documentApi

- getDocument(id)
- getDocuments()
- createDocument(id)

  - onQueryStarted

    - temporaryDocument = makeDocument()
    - dispatch getDocument(id) updateQueryData { Object.assign(draft, temporaryDocument) }
    - dispatch getDocuments updateQueryData { documents.push(temporaryDocument) }

If this is the right way, I must be doing something wrong, because the dispatch getDocument didn't work.

Updating getDocuments works fine.

Maybe there's some interaction with tags I'm missing? Am I overcomplicating things? :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing re: multiple dispatches of `api.util.updateQueryData` should be fine.

The reason that using `updateQueryData` works on `getDocuments` but not on `getDocument(id)` is that `updateQueryData` can only modify pre-existing cache entries.  It cannot create new cache entries.  So you can modify your existing list data to add another item, but you cannot modify the document details for this `id` because there are no document details -- you are creating it right now and have not previously called `getDocument(id)` with this `id` previously.

You need to use [`upsertQueryData`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#upsertquerydata) (requires [v1.9.0+](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.9.0)) instead of `updateQueryData` on your `getDocument(id)` endpoint in order to add a new cache entry for the new document.  The `upsertQueryData` util allows you to insert a new cache entry for a cache key which did not previously exist, or to overwrite an existing version.

You'll keep `updateQueryData` on the `getDocuments` endpoint because in that case you are modifying the existing data.

```
dispatch(api.util.upsertQueryData('getDocument', id, temporaryDocument));
dispatch(api.util.updateQueryData('getDocuments', undefined, (draft) => {
  draft.push(temporaryDocument);
});
```